# How do I add images to select as the desktop's background?

Tags: desktop

Where and/or how should I store images so that they appear in `Preferences/Desktop/Backgrounds`?

Comment: If you're interested I made a script to fade between different wallpapers: https://github.com/agronick/Wallpaper-Slideshow

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can drag&drop them into the backgrounds window and they will automatically appear in the listing.
All the drag&dropped pictures are being copied to `~/.local/share/backgrounds/`.

Comment: Both great answers. Selecting this one since its the simplest. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Background images are stored at `/usr/share/backgrounds`. You can easily copy files to this folder via administrative privileges (either per Files in root mode or `sudo cp`) and they will show up in Switchboard for every user on your computer.

If you don't want to make the new backgrounds available for all users, you can copy wallpapers to `/home/<username>/.local/share/backgrounds`. You don't need administrative privileges and the wallpaper will only be available for your user. As Rafael pointed out, you can also just drag and drop images to the wallpaper selection - It will be added to the folder I mentioned above as well!

Answer (score 0):

Correct local path is `/home/<username>/.local/share/backgrounds` here you can drop images without administrative privileges